# Can I call static method from background queue in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, background

I have a static `getData()` method in the `ServerCommunication` class can I call this method from background queue.

```
//ServerCommunication.swift

import UIKit
import Foundation


class ServerCommunication
{
      class func getData(url: String, sessionId: String) -> ServerResponse {
            //server communication code goes here
      }
}

func populateData() {
     DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
           let response = ServerCommunication.getData(url: URL, sessionId: "")
     }
}
```

Can anybody explain what will the impact on thread executions Or may I need to define `ServerCommunication` class as Singleton?

> getData() static class executed multiple times when calling from background queue

**#Edit1 Some more explanations**

This problem occurred when I am trying to open a specific `viewController` when Push notification occurs. I am using a third party library called [FAPanelController](https://github.com/fahidattique55/FAPanels) which accept a center, left and right viewController respectively.

Code sample:

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
//Now I want to open a viewController
if let panel = self.window?.rootViewController as? FAPanelController     
{
    let centerNavVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! UINavigationController
        let vc = centerNavVC.topViewController as! HomeViewController
        panel.center(centerNavVC, afterThat: {
            //HomeViewController has a method populateData() in viewWillAppear()
        })
}
}
```

Comment: What if you declared `getData` as *not* a `class` method and then you created an instance of `ServerCommunication` in each Dispatch Queue: `let obj = ServerCommunication(); let response = obj.getData(url: URL, sessionId: "")`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Closures` for that

```
class ServerCommunication
{
    class func getData(url: String, sessionId: String, success: @escaping ((_ responseObject: ServerResponse?) -> Void)) {
        //server communication code goes here
        success(serverData) // serverData is a server response
    }
}

func populateData() {
    ServerCommunication.getData(url: "", sessionId: "", success: { (response) in
       // You can handle response here
       print(response)
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain why you are suggested Closures instead of a static class method. Also, can you please briefly what was the disadvantage of using the static class methods?

Comment: @Vishal16 This is not the disadvantage of class methods but this is the advantage of closures in swift and when we are doing something in the background and waiting for the response in the foreground then we have the use closures.

Comment: Ya, I know that static methods don't have any disadvantages but my question is that it will be calling my getData method two times when I am insatiate a view controller from AppDelegate. If I am using your solution still it will be calling my getData method two times. That's why I need a clear explanation about your answer?

Comment: Why this method will call two time?

Comment: That's my question?

Comment: And if you are going to communicate with server then you needed server data whenever you are in viewcontroller. So this is not the problem. But I want to know that from where where you are calling this method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171897/discussion-between-vishal16-and-jogendar-choudhary).

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons of any impact I could imagine:
1. At some point your `getData` modifies UI, which I believe isn't case here.
2. `getData` modifies any variables outside. Thus you need to wrap these modifications in synchronous queue.
3. `getData` calls other mutating methods. The solution is same as in `2`.
Otherwise it's safe to call your static method from anywhere. The Singleton approach is not necessary, unless you need additional setup for your calls.

Comment: Okay but my question is why it will calling getData() method two times?

Comment: @Vishal16 Ah, sorry. So then I guess we need some more details, or you should find all calls (implicit also) to your `populateData()`.

Comment: To make it a bit more clear: This has nothing to do with the method being `static` *per se*. The system doesn't check whether a method is static or not and behaves differently (that would be a really, really horrible thing). It all depends what you do in the method and how you use it. To me it looks like your `HomeViewController`'s `viewWillAppear` is called multiple times. In any way, the result is that you call `getData()` several times, the error is pretty straight forward. Or you have a racing condition (next notification arrives before first finished).

Comment: I am tested with one notification at a time. Is it not that situation?

Comment: Did you check whether the method in which you receive the notification get called twice? {func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)}. I saw that sometimes, the didReceiveResponse method might get called by the system once again!

Answer (score -3):

Yes you can call static method in background thread.

```
ClassName.performSelector(inBackground: #selector(self.ClassMethod), with: nil)
```

Comment: This answer doesn't actually answer the question and it also ignores the way the person asking the question already set up their background thread call. There's no reason to introduce performSelector